# How to autofocus next input field after two-digit numbers/values of specific fields

Tags: javascript, html, input, text, autofocus

I am looking for a solution that allows the cursor to autofocus (according to the tab index and disabled fields) after entering a two-digit number.

I tried to modify that script (works for 1-digit numbers). How to make it work for 2-digit number?

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([disabled])');
let focusableElement;
let maxTries = 100;
let counter = 0;
const getNextElement = (tabeindex) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(`[tabeindex="${tabeindex + 1}"]`)
  if (counter >= maxTries) {
    return;
  }
  if (element && !element.disabled) {
    counter = 0;
    focusableElement = element;
    return;
  }
  counter++
  getNextElement(tabeindex + 1)
}

function focusNextElement (input) {
  const nextIndex = [...inputs].findIndex(i => i === input) + 1
  const tabeindex= +input.getAttribute('tabeindex');
  const element = getNextElement(tabeindex)
  focusableElement.focus()
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td> 1<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="a" name="a" tabeindex="1"></td>
 <td>3<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="b" name="b" tabeindex="3" disabled></td>
 <td>5<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="c" name="c" tabeindex="5">
</td></tr>
<tr>
 <td>2 <input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="d" name="d" tabeindex="2"></td>
 <td>4<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="e" name="e" tabeindex="4"></td>
 <td>6<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="f" name="f"  tabeindex="6""></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe, this was a mistake. Please add the both JavaScript and HTML code into a one snippet. You have added the HTML code out of the snippet.

Comment: Thank you I added it :) So everyone can see how it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jquery-1.7.2.min.js

```js
$(".tes").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next('.tes').focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input class="tes" type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />
<input class="tes" type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />
<input class="tes" type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />
<input class="tes" type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />
<input class="tes" type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />
<input class="tes" type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />
```